# Getting grid column value in Devexpress

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

I am working in .net C# and DevExpress.  I have a situation where I have GridA and GridB (STIWeb:STI_DevExpress_GridView).  What I need to do is, when the row focus changes in GridA, get the key value for the key column in GridA, and do a retrieval and databind in GridB using that key value.

I'm in GridA_FocusRowChanged trying to figure a way to accomplish this whenever the row changes focus, but no success.

Anny suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried, and what about it didn't work? You describe a solution that should work. We need more information to diagnose where the problem is.

Comment: protected void grdA_FocusRowChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     int rowidx = grdA.FocusedRowIndex;
     if (rowidx == 0)
           rowidx = 1;
     string[] result = {  };
                       
     var selrow = grd.GetRowValuesByKeyValue(rowidx, result);

       
}

Comment: Here is what I am trying to do, in the FocusRowChanged event of the grid.  The  "rowidx" value correctly returns the index of the row that is selected, but I am having trouble returning the actual  row from which to procure the value.  The GetRowValuesByKeyValue returns null.  Worse yet, the subsequent firings of FocusRowChanged completely wipe out existing data, so I also need a way to accomplish this through "posting" an event at the end of the queue: (code above this message - sorry, having difficulty formatting on this site)